# Docker gelf log driver - Invalid reference format

Tags: docker, logging, gelf

I am trying to start a docker container and make use the gelf log driver. I run what is in the docs:

```
docker run --log-driver gelf --log-opt gelf-address udp://127.0.0.1:12201 hello-world
```

But that returns:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't find any example of how to format the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is missing in your `log-opt`:

```
docker run \
  --log-driver gelf \
  --log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:12201 \
  hello-world
```

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/#usage